# Making my own Chromebook debug cable (SuzyQ / SuzyQable)

Tags: usb, serial, debugging, adapter, usb-c

While trying to access the CR50 chip in my Dell Latitude 7410 Chromebook, I tried making my own Suzy-Q cable because no online store seems to have some in stock.

I bought some USB breakout boards, and tried to build this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/hdctools/+/master/docs/ccd.md#making-your-own-suzyq with

- GND pins soldered together
- VCC pins soldered together
- Proper resistors (22k and 56k) soldered to VCC pins
- A8 (SBU1) soldered to USB D+
- B8 (SBU1) soldered to USB D-

When connected to the Chromebook, this should trigger USB-C Debug Accessory Mode and expose serial interfaces.

[image: USB-C breakout board 1]
[image: USB type A breakout board]
[image: USB-C breakout board 1]

**My problem:**
After plugging everything to the Chromebook and another Linux computer, I am not having any sign of any serial interface. I tried `lsusb` but nothing appears and `dmesg` does not show anything when I plug or unplug my device (and I have nothing when I try to find `ls /dev/ttyUSB*`).

Of course, I also tried the cable in the other orientation since it is supposed to work only in one orientation.
My soldering skills are quite bad but everything is soldered properly (I double checked, even with a microscope).

Did someone manage to make this kind of cable?
What should I look for?

It seems that user [DannyS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/173011/dannys) ([Making own Chromebook debug cable (SuzyQable)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487226/making-own-chromebook-debug-cable-suzyqable)) had a similar issue but after trying multiple male-to-male USB-C cables (even high-grade Thunderbolt 3 cables), I am still having the same behaviour.

Also, if this is not an hardware issue, does someone know if I have to enable something on my
Linux computer?

Comment: These are 100% very bad solder joints. Might want to watch a few beginner tutorials about soldering - _wetting_ in particular. Solder isn't "hot glue in metal form", but there to make both a mechanical _and_ electrical connection on _both_ metal surfaces.

Comment: Did you make any continuity check for all of the contacts?

Comment: How long is the cable between the breakout boards? Also it doesn't look like the right kind of cable. I'd recommend using a section cut from a proper USB cable instead.

Comment: The solder joints aren't great (excess solder, probably insufficient pre-tinning of the wires) but they don't look bad enough to cause immediate failure. Maybe a side view of the USB2 board to double check for a fillet on D+ and D-.

Comment: I know my solder joints aren't great, I am still learning and I'll do better next time, thank you for your advices!
However, @RohatKılıç, I did continuity checks for all of my joints and contacts, and everything is fine.

Comment: @DamienD the cable between the two boards is 20cm long, but I should definitely try with a section from a proper USB cable, you're right.
Here is what I can see on the USB2 board: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5bOl.jpg
The cable is working well to charge my USB-C mobile phone, thus GND and VCC should at least not be the culprit (I guess)

Comment: @geckoflume yes, try a proper USB cable with a twisted pair for D+ and D- (well SBU) if you're going more than a couple centimetres. Connecting the cable shield is also not a bad idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an important step in the construction of your debug cable. The instructions say to use a *male (plug)* breakout board, while you used a *female (receptacle)* breakout board.

Inside a USB C cable, only 1 CC (A5/B5) is connected to the other side, while a "debugging cable" need both pins connected to a resistor.

You cannot cut your cable, as there is only 1 wire for the CC pins.

You need to use a male (plug) USB C breakout board and wire it up following the instructions

With the way you wired it up now, you basically emulated a normal USB A to C cable in 1 direction, and a 1.5A USB A to C cable in the other direction, not a debugging cable.

Comment: Very good point, now I remember that aspect of the debug accessory mode!

Comment: That must be it! I thought Thunderbolt 3 USB-C cables had everything connected, but this was a wrong assumption. I will try with a male USB-C breakout board, thank you very much!

Comment: @geckoflume only 1 CC line is connected in the cable, the other one is connected to a chip in either plug that says the cable is USB 4.0 and says the maximum charging speed. Some special cables use it to power optical encoders for high speed transfer via glass fibers instead of coppee