# Solderless SuzyQable without Breadboard

Tags: usb, cables, usb-c

Is it possible to wire a SuzyQable without soldering and without a breadboard?

Chromium documentation on how to wire the cable: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/hdctools/+/HEAD/docs/ccd.md#SuzyQ-SuzyQable

Example with breadboard: [Making own Chromebook debug cable (SuzyQable)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487226/making-own-chromebook-debug-cable-suzyqable)

Example without breadboard, with solder. In this video it doesn't show how the USB A 5V to the USBC breakout board is wired, or how the ground is wired on the USBC breakout board: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGsyXlgSxFk

So, with this USB C board that appears to have 2 channels for each of the pins [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09FGT81TX/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09FGT81TX). Along with this USB A to 4-pin cable [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0925H39R3/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0925H39R3). Then using female-to-female jumper wires. Assuming this might be an option to get everything wired with this board, except for how to get 5V to both of the resistors.

```
C       A
-   -   -
A8  FF  D+
B8  FF  D-
A4  FF  5V
A9  FF  A4
B4  FF  A9
B9  FF  A9
A5  FF  22k FF  B9
B5  FF  56k FF  ?
A1  FF  GND
A12 FF  A1
B1  FF  A12
B12 FF  B1
```

Any ideas if it's possible to accomplish a solderless SuzyQable without a breadboard?

Comment: Please add a schematic of the SuzyQable to your question.